# How to use Postgres syntax on Spark dataframe

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I have jdbc connection that running this query using spark:

```
spark.read 
.format("jdbc")
.option("dbtable", "(select * from table subQuery where (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp)) - (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM to_timestamp(event_recorded_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.USZ')))/ 3600 <= 4)
```

lets say I want to use the same filter on df:

```
df1.where("EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM to_timestamp(event_recorded_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.USZ'))/ 3600 <= 4")
```

I am getting: `Literals of type 'EPOCH' are currently not supported for the timestamp type.; line 1 pos 0`

There is a syntax that I can use the same query for both of them and get same results?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `to_unix_timestamp` function to extract `EPOCH` from timestamp.

```
spark
.read
.option(
    "dbtable", 
    "(SELECT
        * 
      FROM
        table subQuery
      WHERE (to_unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) - (to_unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(event_recorded_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.USZ')))/ 3600 <= 4))"
)
```

OR

```
spark
.read
.option(
    "dbtable", 
    "(SELECT
        * 
      FROM
        table subQuery
      WHERE (CAST(CONCAT(TO_UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), '.', REGEXP_EXTRACT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '[0-9]{6}')) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) - (CAST(CONCAT(TO_UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TO_TIMESTAMP(event_recorded_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.USZ'))), '.', REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_TIMESTAMP(event_recorded_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.USZ'), '[0-9]{6}')) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) / 3600 <= 4)"
)
```